# No puedo establecer sesión con Active Directoty

Tags: php, iis, windows-server, ldap

Esto trabajando con Active Directory, tengo desarrollada una función para conectarme al AD y poder crear usuario directamente en PHP. Todo está funcionando correctamente en local, pero cuando paso esa funcionalidad a un servidor deja de funcionar y me manda el siguiente error

`ldap_bind(): Unable to bind to server: Can't contact LDAP serve`

eso significa que si está realizando la conexión `ldap_connect`, pero `ldap_bind` no me está autenticando. Por lo tanto, se conectó, pero no inició sesión con credenciales válidas, pero no entiendo porque si son las mismas credenciales que estoy utilizando en local.

Les comparto mi código tanto en local como en el servidor.

> Código local (sin error)

```
<?php
public function pruebaAD()
{
    // Username used to connect to the server
    // $username = "user";
    $username = "user@user.mx";

    // Password of the user.
    $password = "password";

    // Proper username to connect with.
     $domain_username = "$username";

    // Either an IP or a domain.
    $ldap_server = "xxx.xxx.xxx.x";

    // Get a connection
    $ldap_conn = ldap_connect($ldap_server);

    // Set LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION to 3
    ldap_set_option($ldap_conn, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3) or die ("Could not set LDAP Protocol version");

    // Authenticate the user and link the resource_id with
    // the authentication.
    $ldapbind = ldap_bind($ldap_conn, $domain_username, $password);
    if($ldapbind == true)
    {
    // Setup the data that will be used to create the user
    // This is in the form of a multi-dimensional
    // array that will be passed to AD to insert.

    // Setup the data that will be used to create the user
    // This is in the form of a multi-dimensional
    // array that will be passed to AD to insert.

    $adduserAD["cn"] = "testuser";
    $adduserAD["givenname"] = "Test";
    $adduserAD["sn"] = "User";
    $adduserAD["sAMAccountName"] = "testuser";
    $adduserAD['userPrincipalName'] = "testuser@nagara.ca";
    $adduserAD["objectClass"] = "user";
    $adduserAD["displayname"] = "Test User";
    $adduserAD["userPassword"] = "Password01";
    $adduserAD["userAccountControl"] = "544";

    $base_dn = "cn=testuser,ou=students,DC=nagara,DC=ca";

    // Attempt to add the user with ldap_add()
    if(ldap_add($ldap_conn, $base_dn, $adduserAD) == true)
    {

    // The user is added and should be ready to be logged
    // in to the domain.
    echo "User added!<br>";
    }else{

    // This error message will be displayed if the user
    // was not able to be added to the AD structure.
    echo "Sorry, the user was not added.<br>Error Number: ";
    echo ldap_errno($ldap_conn) . "<br />Error Description: ";
    echo ldap_error($ldap_conn) . "<br />";
    }
    }else{
    echo "Could not bind to the server. Check the username/password.<br />";
    echo "Server Response:"

    // Error number.
    . "<br />Error Number: " . ldap_errno($ldap_conn)

    // Error description.
    . "<br />Description: " . ldap_error($ldap_conn);
    }

    // Always make sure you close the server after
    // your script is finished.
    ldap_close($ldap_conn);
}
?>
```

> Código servidor (con error)

```
<?php
public function pruebaAD()
{
    // Username used to connect to the server
    // $username = "user";
    $username = "user@user.mx";

    // Password of the user.
    $password = "password";

    // Proper username to connect with.
     $domain_username = "$username";

    // Either an IP or a domain.
    $ldap_server = "xxx.xxx.xxx.x";

    // Get a connection
    $ldap_conn = ldap_connect($ldap_server);

    // Set LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION to 3
    ldap_set_option($ldap_conn, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3) or die ("Could not set LDAP Protocol version");

    // Authenticate the user and link the resource_id with
    // the authentication.
    $ldapbind = ldap_bind($ldap_conn, $domain_username, $password);
    if($ldapbind == true)
    {
    // Setup the data that will be used to create the user
    // This is in the form of a multi-dimensional
    // array that will be passed to AD to insert.

    // Setup the data that will be used to create the user
    // This is in the form of a multi-dimensional
    // array that will be passed to AD to insert.

    $adduserAD["cn"] = "testuser";
    $adduserAD["givenname"] = "Test";
    $adduserAD["sn"] = "User";
    $adduserAD["sAMAccountName"] = "testuser";
    $adduserAD['userPrincipalName'] = "testuser@nagara.ca";
    $adduserAD["objectClass"] = "user";
    $adduserAD["displayname"] = "Test User";
    $adduserAD["userPassword"] = "Password01";
    $adduserAD["userAccountControl"] = "544";

    $base_dn = "cn=testuser,ou=students,DC=nagara,DC=ca";

    // Attempt to add the user with ldap_add()
    if(ldap_add($ldap_conn, $base_dn, $adduserAD) == true)
    {

    // The user is added and should be ready to be logged
    // in to the domain.
    echo "User added!<br>";
    }else{

    // This error message will be displayed if the user
    // was not able to be added to the AD structure.
    echo "Sorry, the user was not added.<br>Error Number: ";
    echo ldap_errno($ldap_conn) . "<br />Error Description: ";
    echo ldap_error($ldap_conn) . "<br />";
    }
    }else{
    echo "Could not bind to the server. Check the username/password.<br />";
    echo "Server Response:"

    // Error number.
    . "<br />Error Number: " . ldap_errno($ldap_conn)

    // Error description.
    . "<br />Description: " . ldap_error($ldap_conn);
    }

    // Always make sure you close the server after
    // your script is finished.
    ldap_close($ldap_conn);
}
?>
```

Espero que me puedan apoyar.

Saludos y excelente tarde.

Comment: qué te dice el `ldap_error()`?

Comment: solo manda esto “ldap_bind(): Unable to bind to server: Can't contact LDAP serve”

Comment: bueno... el `can't contact LDAP server` suena a que no hay comunicación hasta el servidor AD. Estás totalmente seguro de que desde el servidor en el que estás alojando la aplicación puedes llegarle al AD? Si es un servidor linux, te diría que pruebes hacer algunas consultas con openldap contra el servidor AD (desde el servidor en el que estás alojando la aplicación).

Comment: y el error me lo esta mandando cuando se esta autenticando "$ldapbind = ldap_bind($ldap_conn, $domain_username, $password);". En esa linea manda error y son las mismas credenciales que utilizo en local donde si se realiza bien todo.

Comment: Si, estoy mirando en la documentación del `ldap_connect`y en realidad esa función no establece la conexión.... solo verifica que los parámetros sean plausibles: **This function does not open a connection. It checks whether the given parameters are plausible and can be used to open a connection as soon as one is needed.** https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-connect.php Así que tiene sentido que falle en el bind, porque ahí si se va a tratar de establecer la conexión. Suena a un issue de red, la verdad.

Comment: Pero como en local si se esta corriendo el proceso correctamente y crea el usuario en el AD?

Comment: SI te es posible, trata de hacer consultas con openldap desde el servidor donde tienes la aplicacion. Eso te permitirá saber si es un problema de conexión de red (puedes intentar algo más sencill como primer paso como tratar de conectarte al puerto delLDAP con telnet, pero ya eso es bastante _bajo nivel_).

Comment: Como? Pues porque la red lo está permitiendo... puede haber un sin fin de razones por las cuales no te puedas conectar desde otro equipo: el otro equipo tiene bien configurada la red para alcanzar el servidor AD? Hay un firewall en el camino? Y así sucesivamente. Tienes que ir descartando los posibles problemas 1 a 1.

Comment: ¿Crees que este bloqueando algún firewall ?

Comment: Ya me fije en el firewall y están abiertos los puertos 389 tanto TCP como UDP.